# How to write query which gives first and last record for each user

Tags: sql

I have tables

```
user_details (mobile_num, log, lat, datetime1)
9999999999 10 10 2014-05-02 09:31:05
9999999999 10 10 2014-05-02 10:00:05
...............
9999999999 10 10 2014-05-02 06:30:05

1111111111 10 10 2014-05-02 09:32:05
1111111111 10 10 2014-05-02 10:00:05
...............
1111111111 10 10 2014-05-02 06:32:05
```

This table update for every minute
This is user table 
    user(mobile_num, name)
    1111111111 A
    9999999999 B

In user_details table I need to get first and last record for each user for today or any date
REsult is

ph num1 name log lat first entry
ph num1 name log lat last entry
ph num2 name log lat first entry
ph num2 name log lat last entry

I am using mysql

I have used this query

select * from user_time_details, user where user_time_details.phone_number = user.phone_num and now_date_time > DATE_SUB(CURDATE()) order by name,id

This will give all entries for today for all users

```
9999999999 10 10 2014-05-02 09:31:05 (first)
9999999999 10 10 2014-05-02 10:00:05
    ...............
9999999999 10 10 2014-05-02 06:30:05 (last)

2222222222 10 10 2014-05-02 09:31:05 (first)
2222222222 10 10 2014-05-02 10:00:05
    ...............
2222222222 10 10 2014-05-02 06:30:05 (last)
```

But I need only first and last record

Comment: Which database system is it?

Comment: And where is the user in your table?

Comment: What columns do you want in your resulting table and what did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

for SQL Server

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME = GETDATE();

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM user_details WHERE DATEDIFF(day, datetime1, @today) = 0 
 ORDER BY datetime1
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM user_details WHERE DATEDIFF(day, datetime1, @today) = 0 
 ORDER BY datetime1 DESC;
```